# Get Image datatype from database and show it when need to print

Tags: asp.net-mvc, angularjs-directive

I Get an image from SQL database. Code in controller is

```
  public ActionResult RetrieveImage(Guid id)
    {
        byte[] cover = GetImageFromDataBase(id);

        if (cover != null)
        {
            return new FileContentResult(cover, "image/jpeg");
        }
        else
        {
            return null;
        }
    }

    public byte[] GetImageFromDataBase(Guid id)
    {
        //UserProfile aUser = new UserProfile();
        Chamber aChamber = new Chamber();
        aChamber = chamberService.GetChamber(id);  // From here i got the image as a datatype[] base64 value
        byte[] cover = aChamber.Logo;
        return cover;
    }
```

and my view page (where i can show this image) is

```
 <img ng-src='/Chamber/RetrieveImage/{{chamberDoctorId.Id}}' id="photo-id-edit" height=20 width=200 style="border:2px solid black" />
```

Problem is in my view page image show successfully ,,but when i want to print this image as using `function PrintElem(elem) {
        //$scope.ForEdit = false;
        Popup($(elem).html());
    }`

```
 only the boarder of the image are found,,but it can't show the image,,,how can i show my image in my print page,,why it isn't show in there??
```

Comment: What element do you pass into `PrintElem` function? If you put `img` in there, `$(elem).html()` will return empty string.

Comment: I pass HTML element,,,and for image print ya,,i pass image ,,But it is not problem,,cause if i pass default pic from any physical location in my application,, it show in printed page,,,but in here i pass the byte[] 64 bit data,,,,,and when i do it it shows empty,,,,,